# C++ detect if type has template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like to unify an interface to work with both templated and non-templated types. Is there a way to determine whether a type, such as a class or a function pointer is depends on a template parameter?

For example:

```
struct foo {};
template<typename T>  struct bar {};

// This works if the template parameter is provided
template<typename> struct is_templated : false_type {};
template<template<typename...> class Obj, typename...Args>
struct is_templated<Obj<Args...>> : true_type {};
template<typename T> constexpr auto is_templated_v = is_templated<T>::value;
```

In this case, `is_template_v<foo>` is false and `is_template_v<bar<int>>` is true, but I can't just deduce anything with `is_template_v<bar>`. Alternatively, if I define

```
template<template<typename...> class> 
struct temp_check : true_type {};
```

Then `temp_check<bar>` is perfectly valid, but I don't know how I would analogously check `foo`. What is needed is something like this if it were valid C++

```
template<template<> class A> struct temp_check<A> : false_type {};
```

Is there some mechanism that could check both?

Comment: `bar<int>` is a specific type. `bar` on the other hand is a template. You can check for both but you need two different specializations of `is_template` to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use the power of overload sets:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {};
template<typename T>  struct bar {};

template<template<class ...> class T, class... TArgs>
constexpr bool is_template() { return true; }

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_template() { return false; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_template<foo>() << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << is_template<bar>() << '\n'; // 1
}
```

Let to the user: use the template function to provide a trait ;)

Comment: This is a nice solution if the types are classes, but is this approach or similar possible if `foo` and `bar` were functions?

Comment: @GregvonWinckel not quite. I would suggest using a class with a call operator in it since manupilating types is much easier than manipulating function pointres