# Check if a type is a template?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to detect whether a type (or more precisely, an identifier as technically a template is not a type) is a template or not, eg to have a function `isTemplate` which behaves the following way:

```
template <typename T>
struct X;
struct Y;
template <int N>
struct Z;

isTemplate<X>(); // Should return true
isTemplate<Y>(); // Should return false
isTemplate<Z>(); // Should return true. This one is especially tricky to get the correct results.
```

How do I implement the `isTemplate` function?

Note: I've tried the following straightforward implementation :

```
template <typename T> // If T is a simple type this overload will be selected
consteval bool isTemplate(int) {
   return false;
}
template <template <class...> class T> // This overload will be selected if T is a template and fits in as a template template parameter
consteval bool isTemplate(char) { // Dummy char parameter to avoid redefinition
   return true;
}
```

But it doesn't work when it needs to detect a template with non-type parameters.

Comment: No. it doesn't work when it needs to detect a template with non-type parameters.

Comment: This question seems a bit confused, as a type cannot "be a template". A template is a means for generating a type, but it is not a type at that point. `Z` is the name of a way to generate a type; it is not a type. `Z<0>` is the name of a type.

Comment: I may be shortsighted, but I don't see the utility of such a trait. Templates aren't types, but rather factories for generating types. A template parameter can't be for both a type *and* a template. It's hardcoded as one or the other. So why would we need to check?

Comment: Ok, I am not checking whether a type is a template, but whether an identifier/name is the name of a template or a simple type. I need to this because I am building a language and I have really weird stuff going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on [YSC's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579461/5023438) to [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54579237/5023438), you can add a function overload that uses an `auto...` parameter pack of non-type template arguments to detect templates accepting non-type arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {};
template<typename T>  struct bar {};
template<int I>  struct baz {};

template<template<class ...> class T>
constexpr bool is_template() { return true; }

// ADDITIONAL SPECIALIZATION for non-type arguments
template<template<auto ...> class T>
constexpr bool is_template() { return true; }

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_template() { return false; }

int main() {
    std::cout << is_template<foo>() << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << is_template<bar>() << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << is_template<baz>() << '\n'; // 1
}
```

[Live Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e228735eb1b443e5)

---

To the best of my knowledge, there is currently no way to define a parameter pack accepting a mixture of both type and non-type template arguments. In practice, this could mean having to write special cases for things like `std::array`.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know about the auto... parameter pack. I'll won't accept the answer just yet just to see if there is a solution which works for mixture of both type and non-type template arguments.

Comment: I feel like there's probably a way to brute-force test for heterogeneous template arguments (types and values) up to a fixed number of arguments by testing instantiations with either SFINAE or C++20's `requires` expressions. It would just require passing a combination of types and `constexpr` values convertible to any `T` type to template arguments. This wouldn't be pretty though.

Comment: @Human-Compiler could you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: @SomeProgrammer I don't really have the time to write this as an answer unfortunately. My thought is to use `index_sequence`s to expand N types and M non-type arguments, where the non-type is just a special type convertible to any type. Then expand this for as many combinations and orders you want to compute whether a template is possible by using it in a SFINAE expression. It would likely work, but it'd also be rather brittle because it would only work for a fixed number of permutations. Generally it's not useful to know whether something is a template anyway.